# Power Automate: Sweep thru Subsites in SharePoint and copy new files

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

Good Day!

I am struggling with the best way to approach this via Power Automate.

Desired Flow:  This will be a scheduled flow that would trigger every 10 minutes.  Cycle through a SharePoint List that contains a list of subsites within my enterprise along with the path to a specific folder in a specific library. Using the 'Apply to Each' function, identify any NEW files since the last sweep.  Copy those files to a different directory in SharePoint (details of which are also included in that same SharePoint list).

I have got all the pieces to this ***EXCEPT***: How to identify the new files since the last sweep.

Can't use the "when a new file is created" trigger, as this listing has close to 300 subsites on it....which would mean 300 different flows.

Appreciate any guidance!

UPDATE:
Getting an error when using the Get Files.  Here is the snippet of the flow:

[Snippet of the Flow Where error is occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Prn.png)

[Snippet of the SharePoint List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoWtM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a Get Files (properties only) action with a Filter Query which uses an Created greater than 10 minutes ago.

Below is an example.

```
Created ge '@{addMinutes(utcNow(), -10)}'
```

[image]

This is for the second part of your question.

[image]

Comment: Getting an error, that I can not quite determine....  
**ExpressionEvaluationFailed. The execution of template action 'Apply_to_each_Hotel' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@items('Apply_to_each')?['field_1']' is of type 'String'. The result must be a valid array.**   The Step before the "Apply to Each" is using the "Get Items" to call up the SharePoint list.

Comment: An apply to each loops expects an array in the Select outputs from previous steps field. It looks like you are using a string instead of an array in that field (the field_1 value). Can you share a screenshot of your setup?

Comment: I added it to the main post, since could not do it in the comments :-)

Comment: Thanks for adding that. That SharePoint Site field is a string value and not a list of items. That is why you are getting that error. You basically need one less apply to each loop. Can you also share a screenshot of your SharePoint List (obfuscate/blur data if needed). This way I can adapt the example I shared earlier to your setup.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense...I Think....I attached a snip of the SharePoint List

Comment: I have added a screenshot for the second part of your question. Btw, I would use Documents instead of Shared Documents in the Directory column of your list. Because Documents is the name of the library.